python: not found after Renaming Jenkins Job when using PyEnv Plugin
When using the PyEnv plugin as such:
withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3') {
   <some code>
}  

I've found that I get an error python: not found after renaming the Jenkins Job.
script.sh.copy: 1: python: not found


It appears that the Pyenv pipeline plugin doesn't handle the job name change well. To fix it, I navigated to the workspace on the slave and forcibly removed the .pyenv-usr-bin-python3/ directory the plugin created. The pipeline worked again after a re-run.
